# Put media into Kinesis Video Streams on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to put a media stream into a Kinesis Video Stream. Since this is not supported within the Javascript SDK yet, I wonder if there is any  solution to get this working without a Java workaround, just pure Javascript.

In the Javascript SDK I can get an endpoint für PutMedia: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KinesisVideo.html - so I wonder why there's a method to get the endpoint but no method to put media via the Javascript SDK.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies.. There is no direct support for the PutMedia API in JS yet. In the meanwhile, the API is described in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_PutMedia.html

You can pre-generate the MKV and issue a POST call directly.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but for those who is still looking:

https://gist.github.com/roccomuso/e65e80aecbe700db2576e751fa1a22c4

```js
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const parseUrl = require('url').parse
// Polyfill, modifying the global Object
require('es6-object-assign').polyfill()
global.Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise
const aws4 = require('aws4')
const axios = require('axios')
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
const fs = require('fs')
const PipeViewer = require('pv')
function noop(){}

const HANGING_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000

/*
const STREAM_NAME = 'test-stream'
const DATA_ENDPOINT = 's-1e413xxx.kinesisvideo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' // returned by getDataEndpoint
const pwd = {
    endpoint: 'kinesisvideo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: " ... ",
    secretAccessKey: " ... ",
}
*/

function sendStream({mkvFile, streamName, dataEndpoint, pwd}, onStart, onFinish){
  onFinish = onFinish || noop

  const opts = {
      service: 'kinesisvideo',
      host: dataEndpoint,
      path: '/putMedia',
      method: 'POST', // NB. required!
      // body: Buffer.from('UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'),
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'x-amzn-stream-name': streamName,
          "x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type": "ABSOLUTE",
          "x-amz-content-sha256":"UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
      }
  }

  const signed = aws4.sign(opts, pwd)

  console.log(signed)

  const reqUri = 'https://' + opts.host+opts.path

  let cancel;

  axios({
    method:'POST',
    timeout: 40*1000,
    url: reqUri,
    headers: signed.headers,
    data: mkvFile,
    responseType: 'stream',
    maxContentLength: Infinity, // required for stream!
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
      cancel = c
    })
  }).then(function(res) {
    onStart && onStart(cancel)
    res.data.on('data', function(fragRes){
      console.log(fragRes.toString())
      fragRes = JSON.parse(fragRes.toString())
      const EventType = fragRes.EventType
      const ErrorCode = fragRes.ErrorCode
      if (EventType === 'ERROR') {
        // request aborted
        onFinish(new Error('Fragment event type: ERROR - ' + ErrorCode))
      }
    })
  }).catch(onFinish)

}


function startUpload ({rtspUri, streamName, dataEndpoint, pwd}){
  // get stream
  const ffmpegVideo = getMkvStream(rtspUri, null, function(err){
    // rtsp error
    if (err) {
      startUpload({rtspUri, streamName, dataEndpoint}) // start again
    }
  })
  const pv = PipeViewer()
  pv.on('info', function(str){
    console.log('Speed: '+str.speed+' - Transferred: '+str.transferred)
  })
  // start send stream
  sendStream({mkvFile: ffmpegVideo.pipe(pv), streamName, dataEndpoint, pwd}, function started(cancel){
    setTimeout(function () {
      cancel() // stop upload
      ffmpegVideo.kill() // stop stream and raise err cb above
    }, 40*60*1000) // 40 min
  }, function finished(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  })
}


function getMkvStream(uri, onStart, onFinished){
  let processHanging = null
  const isRtsp = parseUrl(uri).protocol === 'rtsp:'

  const video = ffmpeg(uri) // also file '/media/desk/Test.mkv'
     //.videoBitrate(500)
     .inputOptions(isRtsp ? ['-rtsp_transport tcp', '-re'] : [])
     .format('matroska')
     .videoCodec('libx264').fps(15)
     .outputOptions(['-map 0:0', '-an', '-g 15', '-vsync 1', '-profile:v baseline',
        '-reset_timestamps 1',
        '-quality good',
        '-cpu-used 2',
        '-pix_fmt yuv420p'
      ])
     .on('progress', function(progress) {
       console.log('Processing:', progress)
       clearTimeout(processHanging)
       processHanging = setTimeout(function(){
         console.error('Hanging for more than 20 sec.')
         video.kill()
       }, HANGING_TIMEOUT) // hanging for more than x sec
      })
     .on('start', function(commandLine) {
       console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine)
       onStart && onStart()
     })
     .on('end', function() {
       console.log('Finished processing')
       onFinished && onFinished()
     })
     .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
       console.log('Cannot process video: ' + err.message)
       clearTimeout(processHanging)
       onFinished && onFinished(err) // eventually restart
     })

    return video
}

/*
// save stream on file:
// getMkvStream('rtsp://admin:@192.168.69.103:554/live1.sdp').pipe().pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('./test.mkv'), null, console.error)
// Kinesis upload USAGE: 
startUpload({
  rtspUri: 'rtsp://admin:@192.168.88.9:554/live1.sdp',
  streamName: 'demo-stream',
  dataEndpoint: 's-4010bf70.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  pwd: {
    endpoint: 'kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    region: 'us-west-2',
    accessKeyId: " ... ",
    secretAccessKey: " ... ",
  }
})
// it spawns ffmpeg and upload stream
*/
```